# Python subprocess module wait method

Tags: python, subprocess, wait

I am learning the subprocess module in python, and to my understanding, the wait method, blocks the thread from executing the rest of the code until the launched process is closed. But when I cann the wait method it still executes the rest of the code:

```
def startCalc():
    x = subprocess.Popen('C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe')
    time.sleep(5)
    x.wait()
    print('finished waiting')
    print(x.poll())
    print(x.wait())

startCalc()
```

If I am not wrong, the "finished waiting statement, would not appear in the output until I close the calculator, but it does.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: If you type `calc.exe` at a Windows command prompt, you get another prompt almost immediately - even though the calculator window is still open.  Apparently, `calc.exe` launches the actual program, and then exits - I have no idea why it works this way.

Comment: Nomenclature: threads and processes are different things; there are no threads here (other than in the trivial sense that every process which doesn't use threading executes in a single thread by definition).

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with your code, but rather with the `calc.exe` executable. It starts the calculator and returns immediately with 0 exit status. So, from the perspective of your program, the process ran to completion successfully. As far as I know, `calc.exe` doesn't have a way to launch in attached mode.

Test this by opening a powershell, or cmd terminal and launching `calc.exe`. You get the prompt back immediately.

Comment: I just tried this code with another executable, and it seems that the calc.exe behaves differently than some other .exe programs.

Comment: However when I launch a .py script, and call for the wait() method I receive this error: 
```AttributeError: 'CompletedProcess' object has no attribute 'wait'```

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with the ".wait" function, but if you want your code to wait for the execution of the "calc.exe" process, you could replace "Popen" with "call":

```
x = subprocess.call('C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe')
```